# Overlay an acroForm on all pages with pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to use pdfbox to take a one page pdf (the overlay) that has some form fields and overlay it on top of every page of another pdf. The result should have the form fields that are still interactive. The overlay also has several javascript actions as well as a document level javascript.

My attempts so far have resulted in the overlay being applied without the form elements nor the javascript. I think I've found a way to work around the javascript thing by adding it separately afterwards. The problem is he javascript needs to interact with the form field elements that are no longer around.

I've tried several different strategies, trying to use all the classes that I could (overlay, util.overlay, layerUtility).

In an effort to clarify my end goal in case there is a better way to achieve it: We're currently using another software to ahead-of-time apply the overlay and are using the overlay form fields to cover up the content of the pdf and the javascript to show or hide the form fields depending on if the document has "expired" according to some document metadata we have applied to the pdf. We also use the javascript and form fields to do dynamic headers and footers triggered by the print action. I'm looking for ways to add the overlay and javascript more on-the-fly.

I'm currently trying to stick with 1.8.x since we already have that in some other libraries in our project.

Thanks for your help!

The attempt that feels most correct. It adds the overlay but without the form fields:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PDDocument pdf = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("argument:" + args[0]);
        pdf = PDDocument.load(new File(args[0]));
        addOverlay(pdf); //flattens overlay, fields lost.    
        pdf.save("output.pdf");
        pdf.close();
    } finally {
        if (pdf != null) {
            pdf.close();
        }
    }
    return;
}

private static void mergeOverlay(final PDDocument pdf) throws IOException {
    PDDocument overlayPDF = PDDocument.load(new File("overlay.pdf"));
    Overlay overlay = new Overlay();
    overlay.overlay(overlayPDF, pdf);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, form field widgets (or actually any annotations) of a page and also document-level data get lost when that page is added to some page of another document using `Overlay`. Therefore one should usually take the pdf with annotations as base document to which some other page is added. Thus, consider inverting control. In your case there is a complication, though, you want to have the form fields on every page of the result PDF. In that context please clarify, do you want all the corresponding fields on different pages to display the same value or independent ones?

Comment: All the fields on the resulting pages can have the same values. Essentially there are 3 or 4 fields. One for a dynamic header, one for a dynamic footer, and the most important one the one that covers the whole page and says something like: "You're not permitted to view this document, log in to the system and grab a current version"

Comment: If I understand correctly you suggest that I invert which document is the overlay and which is the "source" pdf. I'm concerned about that too because the source pdf may have fields as well.

Comment: *"the source pdf may have fields as well"* - ah. Hm, as far as I know that use case is not covered by `Overlay`, at least not out of the box.

Comment: As you want to add very specific fields and contents, how about adding them explicitly using pdfbox form related methods?

Comment: I've started going down that path today. It's a bit more heavy handed than I wanted to be and I'm a bit worried about introducing new behavior or results that they don't see on our current system but it might be the best I have. I'll update here after I have a go at that strategy.

Comment: Have you been successful? Or do you need some input?

Comment: Thanks for checking back. I ran into issues and pivoted my strategy again. I went back to my original strategy of trying to remove the javascript and the form field that obscures the document. I had more success but then I had to fill in a couple of the fields (header and footer) using pdfbox. It seemed to work until I had a pdf with non-latin characters. I struggled trying to piece together a solution from all the examples I could find. I've not had full success in that regard yet.

Comment: As the state of your issue has changed considerably, you may want to rewrite the question completely to reflect that.